# notation confusion in C when variable is a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I am confused about a notation in C when I have a pointer variable `f` pointing to a `struct X` defined as:

```
struct Y {
    int d;
    struct X *e;
};

struct X {
    int *a;
    int b[4];
    struct Y c;
};
```

Then I have this:

```
f->c.e->c.e[0].a[0]
```

The thing I don't understand is the part `c.e[0].a[0]`.

I am not sure what is `c.e[0]` and then also what is `c.e[0].a[0]`. (also not sure whether `c.e[0]` is 20-offset from the starting address of a `struct X`). Assuming here pointer is 4 bytes, integer is 4 bytes. So `int *a` + `int b[4]` + `int d` = 20 offset?
is it the meaning of `f->c.e->c.e[0]`? is there `f->c.e->c.e[3]`?  `f->c.e->c.e[4]`? `f->c.e->c.e[5]`?

I am confused because usually for a pointer variable say `k`, I always see `k->x`, `k->y`, `k->l`  to refer to the variables within a struct when the variable `k` is pointing to the struct variable. However in this case, I see the notation of `c.e->c.e[0].a[0]`. Is `e[0].a[0]` valid? I guess `e[0]` is not a pointer then, since if it is a pointer `e[0]` must always use the `->` notation to refer to a variable within a struct it pointing to, but since it uses (dot `.`) instead of (arrow `->`), `e[0].a[0]` so I guess `e[0]` in this case is not a pointer right?

then I am little confused as to what is the meaning of `c.e[0].a[0]` in my given `struct X`, `struct Y`, and the given pointer variable `f` here.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Post text as properly formatted text. [Edit] your question.

Comment: That depends on what `a` and `e` actually point to. In this notation, it hints at them pointing to the starting elements of arrays, `[0]` being the same as `*`.

Comment: In fact, if this really was the whole code, I'd expect your program to crash upon execution, because both `a` and `e` are either un- or zero initialized, meaning that by dereferencing, you are accessing invalid memory.

Answer (score 3):

`c.e` is a pointer to a `struct X`, so `c.e[0]` is the `struct X` pointed to by `c.e`.

If `c.e` is a pointer to the first element of an array of 4 `struct Y`, the 4 elements of this array could be referred to as `c.e[0]`, `c.e[1]`, `c.e[2]` and `c.e[3]`.

For all pointers `p`, `p[0]` is equivalent to `*p` or `*(p + 0)` (or even `0[p]`).

In this case, `f->c.e->c.e[0].a[0]` is equivalent to `f->c.e->c.e->a[0]` and `*f->c.e->c.e->a`. Which syntax is used is a question of style and readability. The array syntax using `[]` is usually more readable when the index is or can be different from zero, in case of pointers to single objects, the `->` syntax is preferred.

The actual implementation details, such as pointer and integer sizes is irrelevant here, but bear in mind that the offset of a member in a structure may be affected by alignment constraints: for example in most current 64-bit systems, an `int` still has 4 bytes but a pointer uses 8 bytes, so the offset of `e` in `struct Y` must be aligned on a multiple of `8`, hence is `8`, not `4`. 4 padding bytes are inserted between `d` and `e`. Note also that if `d` is meant to store the number of elements in the array pointed to by `e`, it should probably be defined with type `size_t`.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion comes from the multiple ways of using pointers in C.

Declaring a simple array goes as follow:

```c
<type> <name>[<size>];
// More concretely
int array_of_ints[5];
// Accessing its elements is straightforward
array_of_ints[0] = 42;
```

But what if you can't know the size in advance? You'd have to allocate memory with e.g. `malloc` which gives you a pointer to the beginning of the array:

```c
int * array_of_ints = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
// Access its elements the same way as arrays declared on the stack
array_of_ints[0] = 42;
```

How come the same syntax can be used for both types (`int[5]` vs. `int *`)?

This is because under the hood the compiler treats it the exact same way. **The name of the array is actually a pointer to its first element**, as we can see here:

```c
void foo(int * array)
{
    printf("%d\n", *array); // *array and array[0] are interchangeable
}

int bar()
{
    int array[5];
    array[0] = 42;
    foo(array);
}
```

So an array can be **decayed** into a pointer. And the language lets you use the `[]` operator because the compiler actually translates it using **pointer arithmetic**:

> `array[0]` is the same as `*array` but, more precisely, the same as `*(array + 0)`.

So how do you know if you have a pointer to a single value or a pointer to a value that's the first value of an array? Well, without context, you can't. From an isolated function's perspective, you can't know if taking a `char *` parameter means it is a string argument or a pointer to a single char variable. It's up to the developers to make it clear, either by passing the size of the array along with it, or naming the variable correctly (`char * str` vs. `char * c` for instance), writing documentation, etc.